# Can I draw a variable resistor with an arrow looking to the left? What does the side the arrow look at signifiy?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, conventions, notation

**Like this:**
[image]

**Instead of this:**

[image]

And what does the direction that the arrow look at signify?

Comment: There’s no difference.

Comment: It signifies nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the old days a variable resistor (or *potentiometer* or *rheostat*) was typically made using a coil of wire with a sliding contact that can be moved along the wire. There is a nice picture of this [on the Components 101 site](https://components101.com/articles/how-digital-potentiometer-works-and-how-to-use-it):

[image: Rheostat]

[image: Diagram]

The symbol for a variable resistor was derived from this:

[image: Symbol]

Life being too short the symbol was subsequently simplified to the form you show i.e. just a resistor with the arrow drawn in some vague way over the top of it. There is no special significance to the position and direction of the arrow (except possible whether the author is left or right handed).

Comment: I'm so happy there's no difference! My teacher made me lose marks when I drew the arrow the other way around, hence why I'm asking. And yeah I think so too; as a leftie I've a natural tendency to draw it with the arrow to the left, just like I do with a check mark.